# How to change someone's hebrew name?

Tags: hebrew, names, how-to

I am wondering how to change officially someone's hebrew name. I have seen in the Tora that Hashem changes people's names. Like Sarai became Sarah, Avram became Avraham,Yaaqob became Yisrael, Yetkuel became Moshe.