# Getting a Jewish name

Tags: names

What is the procedure for giving a Jew a Jewish name if he or she was never given one at birth?

Are there any sources that discuss this situation?

Comment: What's a "Jewish name"? Presumably the person is already Jewish and already has a name. Please edit to clarify

Comment: He may be asking about a case where his name is "jesus" and wants a jewish name,how does one go about that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change someone's hebrew name?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71636/how-to-change-someones-hebrew-name)

Comment: @sam if "Jesus" werent a Jewish name, why did Jesus have it?

Comment: Yeshua is the Hebrew form,Jesus is not a jewish name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing one's Hebrew name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36055/changing-ones-hebrew-name)

Comment: @Sam so my (English) name is not Jewish? That may come as a surprise to the other 5% of the male Jewish population in the English speaking world I share it with. How about your name?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. Those discuss *changing* one’s name, which may or may not be the same as getting a Jewish name (however the OP means that, which I assume is the usually Hebrew name usually given shortly after one’s birth) when one never had one.

Comment: If you weren’t given a Hebrew name at birth basically you can just choose one for yourself (like a convert does) or go by your given name. You don’t have to have a Hebrew name to be called for an aliyah. Consider people with Yiddish names...

Comment: I am not sure what is so difficult to understand about this question. If someone wishes to give himself or herself a Jewish or biblical name is there any procedure?

Comment: @ElShteiger ,don't take it personally, your question is a good question ,sometimes people like to give some of the questioners a hard time to make the question more clear, in this actual case your question is clear .